# Creating a TermQuery with a List by using Elasticsearch Java API Client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I am trying to convert some Java High Level REST Client code to new [Elasticsearch Java API Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/index.html).

I want to convert this query which retrieves the contents if the id is equal to 10 or 20.

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest().indices(indexName);

    List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    ids.add(10l);
    ids.add(20l);

    SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();

    searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
        .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("id", ids)));

        searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
```

With the new Java API Client I've built something like this.

```
TermsQueryField termsQueryField = new TermsQueryField.Builder()
         .value(/*Expects List<FieldValue>*/)
         .build();

TermsQuery idTerms = new TermsQuery.Builder()
        .field("id")
        .terms(termsQueryField)
        .build();

Query idQuery = new Query.Builder()
        .terms(idTerms)
        .build();

BoolQuery boolQuery = new BoolQuery.Builder()
        .must(idQuery)
        .build();

Query query = new Query.Builder()
        .bool(boolQuery)
        .build();

SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest.Builder()
        .index(indexName)
        .query(query)
        .build();
```

I can add the `termQuery` options for single values but I could not find a way to add a list to the query.

I've came across with `TermsQuery` but that requires the values to be set as a `List<FieldValue>` so that's not very helpful.

Note: I know I can use lambda expressions for constructing these objects but I am trying to be as verbose as possible until I figure out how to use the new client.

Comment: You can create two different `TermQuery` query in a `bool`->`should` clause. You cannot send multiple values to `TermQuery` becasue it expects a single value. Or you can use the `TermsQuery` as you stated in your question

Comment: Have you tried building that `List<FieldValue>`? Should be straightforward enough: just instantiate an `ArrayList` and then do `lst.add(FieldValue.of("strValue")`

Comment: @ilvar Yes I know I can do that but that doesn't sound efficient. Why should I have to loop every ID just to create a query? There must be an easier way. That's what I am looking for.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm trying to the same. I'm finding the new Java Client quite...cumbersome / terrible for examples

Comment: @MetaCoder I don't have any solutions at the moment. Sorry about that. I can't remember how I solved this but I believe it was not a pretty one so I did not post an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Using streams seems currently to be the simplest way to create the list of terms:

```
List<String> countries = List.of("afg", "aus");

TermsQueryField countryTerms = new TermsQueryField.Builder()
    .value(countries.stream().map(FieldValue::of).toList())
    .build();

SearchRequest sr = SearchRequest.of(s -> s
    .query(q -> q
        .bool(b -> b 
            .filter(mCtry -> mCtry
                .bool(bCtry -> bCtry
                    .should(shdCtry -> shdCtry
                        .terms(tCtry -> tCtry
                            .field("country")
                            .terms(countryTerms)
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolQuery like this

```
boolQuery().apply {
            ids.forEach {
                should(matchQuery("test.id", it))
            }
        }
```

Above solution has a limit on the criterias to add. Otherwise use

```
(termsQuery("FIELD", [value1, value2,value3])
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code is also working.

```
TermsQueryField countryTerms = new TermsQueryField.Builder()
.value(countries.stream().map(FieldValue::of).toList())
.build();

SearchRequest sr = SearchRequest.of(s -> s
            .query(q -> q
                    .bool(bCtry -> bCtry
                            .should(shdCtry -> shdCtry
                                    .terms(tCtry -> tCtry
                                            .field("country")
                                            .terms(countryTerms)
                                    )
                            )
                    )
            )
    );
```